# Dealing with different types in a fact table

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, olap, dimensional-modeling, star-schema

I'm working with dimensional modelling for the first time, trying to build a data warehouse that pulls in data from an OLTP database, and I'm having some trouble figuring out what to do with this type of scenario. The database tracks donations into a foundation. I'd like to have a fact table such that the "grain" is a single donation, i.e. at the "transaction" level. Donations can come from different types of donors. Let's say for example they come from individuals and companies, although in practice there are actually four relevant categories. The source data has tables for each of these donor types--so there is an `individuals` table and a `companies` table. Individuals and companies have very different attributes, and a typical reporting requirement will be to look at aggregate donations for all types, and then do deeper dives into donations by donor type. My first thought was to build a schema like so

(the colour is meaningless btw, I just happened to take the screenshot when the highlighted table was selected)

[image: Schema 1]

Since companies and individuals have such different attributes, the idea was to keep them in their own tables and have them be dimensions. (Remember that there are actually 4+ types like this in the real case).

But this is apparently not a good way to go because that means that there will be lots of NULL foreign keys in the fact table. I have read that this is a no-no (although I'm not sure why).

Another option would be to combine the Companies and Users tables into one big Donors table, which might look like this

[image]

This eliminates the NULL foreign keys from the fact table at the expense of simplicity in the dimension table. The Donor dimension table is now very wide, and contains *a lot* of null attributes (again, remember that there are 4+ types of donors that would be represented, each with its own unique attributes).

Finally, there is the option of having a Donor dimension that references Company and Individual tables. Here's how that might look:

[image]

Now all the null foreign keys are in the donor dimension table. Obviously, however, this is no longer a star schema.

I've been searching everywhere I can think of to find some general principles for dealing with this type of situation, but I'm coming up short. I'm just wondering if there is a standard way to deal with this since it seems like it ought to be a standard problem in data warehousing.

Comment: In short: nulls don't join. Unless you use an outer join. Which is needless additional processing. If you have a record whose FK is null, as soon as you select from that dimension, the record disappears. Plus you can add lots of interesting dimension members that give more info about why it's missing.

Comment: you are ending with moving towards snowflake, nothing wrong with that. You can take help of surrogate key which is recommended in data warehousing.

Answer (score 4):

I would steer clear of the 3 option. It's called a snowflake instead of a star schema. It's a rather advanced solution which can be used when necessary but has it's own drawbacks. As usual refer to Kimball when looking for datawarehouse design tips.

This is what they say in [Snowflakes, Outriggers, and Bridges](http://www.kimballgroup.com/2008/09/design-tip-105-snowflakes-outriggers-and-bridges/):

> We generally encourage you to handle many-to-one hierarchical
>   relationships in a single dimension table rather than snowflaking.
>   Snowflakes may appear optimal to an experienced OLTP data modeler, but
>   they’re suboptimal for DW/BI query performance. The linked snowflaked
>   tables create complexity and confusion for users directly exposed to
>   the table structures; even if users are buffered from the tables,
>   snowflaking increases complexity

When it comes to 1 or 2, I would say it's up to the reporting requirements and how well the dimension members (the records in the dimension) should be seen as one "axis" to report against. There can be benefits to combining multiple types of records in a single dimension (such as defining hierarchies and attribute relationships to improve performance) but in this case I would lean towards seperate dimensions for different entities.
Again, Kimball explains this in the [basics of dimensional modeling](http://www.kimballgroup.com/2009/05/the-10-essential-rules-of-dimensional-modeling/) but they have more articles on the subject.

> Rule #1: Load detailed atomic data into dimensional structures.
>
> Rule #2: Structure dimensional models around business processes.
>
> Rule #8: Make certain that dimension tables use a surrogate key.

When it comes to NULL values in your fact table foreign keys, those should be solved by using `surrogate keys` which you should use anyway.

I [answered a related question here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/187743/39384) but it basically comes down again to [Selecting Default Values for Nulls](http://www.kimballgroup.com/2010/10/design-tip-128-selecting-default-values-for-nulls/) which explains how you should handle missing data in your dimensions.

> The first scenario where nulls should be avoided is when we encounter
>   a null value as a foreign key for a fact table row during the ETL
>   process. We must do something in this case because an actual null
>   value in a foreign key field of a fact table will violate referential
>   integrity;

In some way you can interpret that as "NULLS are a no-no" but it actually means "insert a dummy record such as N/A in your dimension, and use the surrogate key of that record in your fact tables foreign key field"

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for your answer! I'm trying to understand why a default value for option 1 is preferable to NULL foreign keys. From what I can tell, the queries are simpler with the NULL foreign keys. Say I want to select all donations from companies. The query is `select * from donations d, companies c where d.company_id = c.company_id`. But with default values I need to add another where condition. How is that better?

Comment: @crf Have you read my answer to the other question? Error configuration replacing null values is slow (at least in SSAS/SQL Server).

Comment: @crf do you have an ETL process?

Comment: and @crf are you using SQL Server?

Comment: I'm using Amazon Redshift. My ETL process is roughly as follows. I copy relevant tables direct from OLTP database to a staging schema on Redshift. Then I run some SQL scripts on Redshift to transform tables from the staging schema to a main data warehouse schema.

Comment: Why can't you add a single record `-1`=`not applicable` to your dimension and add an `update fact set dimkey=-1 where dimkey is null` or something in your ETL, that way you would end up with a non null foreign key in your star schema

Comment: And as kimball explains, the -1 could be replaced by several "data cleansing" solutions such as "not applicable", "applicable but illegal data", "applicable but data probably not loaded yet" etc, it offers a lot more flexibility

Answer (score 1):

@TomV Already answered this well, essentially if you want to split each case into separate dimensions you create a dummy record with a surrogate key. Can't say if it's right for your business case but it is common.

For the sake of completeness here is the word from Kimball regarding NULL's in Fact tables:

> Null-valued measurements behave gracefully in fact tables. The
>   aggregate functions (SUM, COUNT, MIN, MAX, and AVG) all do the “right
>   thing” with null facts. However, nulls must be avoided in the fact
>   table’s foreign keys because these nulls would automatically cause a
>   referential integrity violation. Rather than a null foreign key, the
>   associated dimension table must have a default row (and surrogate key)
>   representing the unknown or not applicable condition.